# Request::is() with variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have route like this

```
Route::get('/edit_faq/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@add_faq');
```

with prefix

> admin

and i want to use `Request::is()` but didn't find any thing to use with variable . 
also i am using this in blade file like this

> if("{{Request::is('admin/faq')}}"){}

is there any way to check this in blade like we do in route file just by declaring variable {id}

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide arguments to it.

```
@if(Request::is('admin/faq', 'admin/edit_faq/*'))
```

Then it will match with any of the given arguments. Hope you are looking for this only.

Comment: Do you have route ```admin/faq```? Are you calling ```admin/faq``` route for calling view in which your code is written?

Comment: no i m dd the admin/edit_faq/{$variable} but i don't want to put value in it , it has to work like route in which what ever the value are it pass

Comment: @GauravGupta I have upadet my answer use ```*``` wildcard to match it. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation like yours where I wanted to add a variable to `Request::is()` for a list with a `foreach` loop in a `laravel` blade template.

```
class="{{ Request::is('*items/edit/'.$item->id) ? 'active' : '' }}"
```

Add variable outside ' ' and it will work.

Comment: thank you for your response but my problem already solve by above answer thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

correct way to use in blade file is like this:

```
@if(Request::is('admin/faq'))
...
@endif
```

in controller :

```
if ($request->is('admin/*')) {
    //
}
```

> The is method allows you to verify that the incoming request path
>   matches a given pattern. You may use the * character as a wildcard
>   when utilizing this method:

Comment: i know that , what i want is how to use it with variable route as define above in question

Comment: @GauravGupta variable route?!! what does it mean? I think its better to say what do you looking for